# importhtml function doesn't work with specific website setup

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am working with importing data from the internet into my google sheets sheet and the website I am working with has the table split up in to pages but when I click page 2, the URL does not change to represent that change meaning I can't import all the pages after page 1. How can I alter the formula or import a different way in order to fix this? I don't want to copy the data myself because I would like to have dynamic data on this sheet. The website in question is:

https://www.lineups.com/nfl/player-ratings

Thank you

I tried to pretend the tables were on the same page and import table 2 but it does not bring anything in. I don't know what else to do.